# Quart infinite/indefinite streaming response

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, quart

I am trying to create a server (loosely) based on [an old blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited) to stream video with Quart.

To stream video to a client, it seems all I should need to do is have a route that returns a generator of frames. However, actually doing this results in a constant repeated message of `socket.send() raised exception`, and shows a broken image on the client. After that, the server does not appear to respond to further requests.

Using more inspiration from the original post, I tried returning a `Response` (using `return Response(generator, mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")`.) This does actually display video on the client, but as soon as they disconnect (close the tab, navigate to another page, etc) the server begins spamming `socket.send() raised exception` again and does not respond to further requests.

My code is below.

```
# in app.py
from camera_opencv import Camera
import os
from quart import (
    Quart,
    render_template,
    Response,
    send_from_directory,
)

app = Quart(__name__)

async def gen(c: Camera):
    for frame in c.frames():
        # d_frame = cv_processing.draw_debugs_jpegs(c.get_frame()[1])
        yield (b"--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" + frame[0] + b"\r\n")


c_gen = gen(Camera(0))


@app.route("/video_feed")
async def feed():
    """Streaming route (img src)"""
    # return c_gen
    return Response(c_gen, mimetype="multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")

# in camera_opencv.py
from asyncio import Event
import cv2

class Camera:
    last_frame = []

    def __init__(self, source: int):
        self.video_source = source
        self.cv2_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_source)
        self.event = Event()

    def set_video_source(self, source):
        self.video_source = source
        self.cv2_cam = cv2.VideoCapture(self.video_source)

    async def get_frame(self):
        await self.event.wait()
        self.event.clear()
        return Camera.last_frame

    def frames(self):
        if not self.cv2_cam.isOpened():
            raise RuntimeError("Could not start camera.")

        while True:
            # read current frame
            _, img = self.cv2_cam.read()

            # encode as a jpeg image and return it
            Camera.last_frame = [cv2.imencode(".jpg", img)[1].tobytes(), img]
            self.event.set()
            yield Camera.last_frame
        self.cv2_cam.release()
```

Comment: Your code looks good, and I think this is a bug with Quart that is now fixed in master. See https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/issues/154.

Comment: @pgjones Will that be pushed to PyPi soon? There aren't instructions on source installation in the repository (+ updating from pip is easier)

Comment: I've just pushed 0.6.9, so it should be available now.

Comment: Hmm. Updated Quart and hypercorn (`pip install -U Quart hypercorn`) and now starting `app.py` gives `RuntimeError: ASGI Scope type is unknown` (and rejects all connections, followed by a `TimeoutError`.) I'll open a GitLab issue later today.

Comment: Sadly the Hypercorn 0.4.0 release introduced a new bug, which I've now fixed with Hypercorn 0.4.1. Could you upgrade and try it? I think then this should be good.

Comment: Well, save the `ASGI Framework Lifespan error, continuing without Lifespan support` message on startup, everything seems to be in working order now! I'll post an answer summary soonish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was originally [an issue with Quart itself.](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/issues/154)

After a round of bugfixes to both Quart and Hypercorn, the code as posted functions as intended (as of 2018-11-13.)